# Seeking optimal way to handle constructors of struct with overlapping fields

Tags: c#, memory, data-structures, constructor

I've created a custom structure for handling RGBA values that will be marshaled to the GPU.

In my type, I am holding individual R, G, B and A components as byte values and am overlapping a 32-bit unsigned integer (Uint32) to easily pass and assign the packed value. I know the concept is obvious but here's a sample of the struct for good measure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 4)]
public struct RGBA
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint32 PackedValue;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte R;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte G;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte B;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte A;
}
```

Because of the way c# handles structs, each field must be assigned explicitly in any constructor defined. In my case, that means I have to assign the values twice in any constructors because of the overlapping fields.

I could either use:

```
public RGBA(uint packed value)
{
    R = G = B = A = 0;    //  initialize all to defaults before assigning packed value
    PackedValue = packedValue;
}

public RGBA(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a)
{
    PackedValue = 0;    // initialize to default before assigning components
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
    A = a;
}
```

or I could call the base constructor on each constructor first like so:

```
public RGBA(uint packedValue) : this()
{
    PackedValue = packedValue;
}

public RGBA(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a) : this()
{
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
    A = a;
}
```

Since this is for use in graphics code, performance is critical and I'm trying to find the most optimal way to handle constructing in this scenario. Using the first example seems the least overhead of the two examples, since although it involves assigning all fields twice (once for PackedValue, and once for the R, G, B and A fields), the other example involves assigning all values 3 times (twice in the default constructor and once in the defined constructor).

Is there a way to make the compiler recognize that these fields overlap and shouldn't require assigning explicitly R,G,B and A if PackedValue is being assigned and vice-versa? I'm assuming this could be done by manually tweaking the IL generated but I'm wondering if there is a way to handle this more optimally directly in c#.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you use properties to avoid double-initialization? E.g. `public byte A { get { return (byte)(PackedValue >> 24); } }`?

Comment: Good question . . .  have you tried any benchmarking?  Perhaps the compiler is smart enough to elide some of the useless calls.

Comment: I suppose I could use bit-wise ops on the packed value so that the R,G,B and A fields dont have to be allocated. The overhead added by get/set code is undesired, but I may have to if the compiler wont play nice. Not sure how it'll behave on the GPU though once marshalled

Comment: You'll have to benchmark this. It is unclear what the JIT does. The CLR JIT is not that good at optimizing stuff. Look at the disassembly in Release mode with optimizations turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208(v=vs.71).aspx):

Struct members are automatically initialized to their default values. So, no need to initialize any of them to their default values, in either constructor.

**However, that does not apply to your case. It works only for non-overlapped fields and only when you use the default constructor. Anyway, see last part of the answer for an alternative based on this.**

Looking at the IL code for the one-param constructor we can see that the compiler does nothing (no optimization, this is release mode with default settings):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(uint32 packedValue) cil managed
{
  // Code size       42 (0x2a)
  .maxstack  6
  .locals init ([0] uint8 CS$0$0000,
           [1] uint8 CS$0$0001,
           [2] uint8 CS$0$0002)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldarg.0
  IL_0003:  ldarg.0
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0005:  dup
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  stfld      uint8 ConsoleApplication2.Program/RGBA::A
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  dup
  IL_000e:  stloc.1
  IL_000f:  stfld      uint8 ConsoleApplication2.Program/RGBA::B
  IL_0014:  ldloc.1
  IL_0015:  dup
  IL_0016:  stloc.2
  IL_0017:  stfld      uint8 ConsoleApplication2.Program/RGBA::G
  IL_001c:  ldloc.2
  IL_001d:  stfld      uint8 ConsoleApplication2.Program/RGBA::R
  IL_0022:  ldarg.0
  IL_0023:  ldarg.1
  IL_0024:  stfld      uint32 ConsoleApplication2.Program/RGBA::PackedValue
  IL_0029:  ret
} // end of method RGBA::.ctor
```

After @usr's suggestion, after jitting it looks the same (this is also release mode, members assigned individually):

```
007400B5  call        750586FE  
007400BA  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
007400BD  mov         byte ptr [eax],0  
                G = 0;
007400C0  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
007400C3  mov         byte ptr [eax+1],0  
                B = 0; 
007400C7  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
007400CA  mov         byte ptr [eax+2],0  
                A = 0;
007400CE  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
007400D1  mov         byte ptr [eax+3],0  
                PackedValue = packedValue;
007400D5  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
007400D8  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4]  
007400DB  mov         dword ptr [eax],edx
```

Perhaps benchmarking it is the best way now. Or, use a default constructor and assign `PackedValue` manually after you have the struct instance. In this case the default behavior described in the article will apply.

```
var rgba = new RGBA { PackedValue = 2556 };
```

OR

```
var rgba = new RGBA();
rgba.PackedValue = 2556;
```

Comment: @marceln Agreed. After really looking at the problem I think benchmarking and picking the lesser of evils is the only way here. It's the trade-off for emulating unions in c# i suppose lol. Since it's intended for marshaling to native graphics apis, the functions usually provide overloads that accept packed ints anyway so I guess the component fields could be considered syntactic sugar on the  managed side in my case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the type to provide that IL by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and ended up using unsafe code to convert my Color struct into a 32 bit integer and back. Not sure if that's an option for you.